# Mongorestore in a Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, mongorestore

I want to create a Docker image that starts a mongo server and automatically restores from a previous `mongodump` on startup.

---

Here is my Dockerfile for the image:

```
 FROM mongo

 COPY dump /home/dump

 CMD mongorestore /home/dump
```

When I run this, I run into this error:

> `Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`

---

**Is there any way to get the `mongorestore` command to run through Docker?**

Answer (score 18):

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354167/3692084), Marc Young's answer, and the Dockerfile reference I was able to get this working.

---

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM mongo

COPY dump /home/dump
COPY mongo.sh /home/mongo.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/mongo.sh

CMD /home/mongo.sh
```

**`mongo.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize a mongo data folder and logfile
mkdir -p /data/db
touch /var/log/mongodb.log
chmod 777 /var/log/mongodb.log

# Start mongodb with logging
# --logpath    Without this mongod will output all log information to the standard output.
# --logappend  Ensure mongod appends new entries to the end of the logfile. We create it first so that the below tail always finds something
/entrypoint.sh mongod --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend &

# Wait until mongo logs that it's ready (or timeout after 60s)
COUNTER=0
grep -q 'waiting for connections on port' /var/log/mongodb.log
while [[ $? -ne 0 && $COUNTER -lt 60 ]] ; do
    sleep 2
    let COUNTER+=2
    echo "Waiting for mongo to initialize... ($COUNTER seconds so far)"
    grep -q 'waiting for connections on port' /var/log/mongodb.log
done

# Restore from dump
mongorestore --drop /home/dump

# Keep container running
tail -f /dev/null
```

---

Comment: I moved the `mongorestore` command to the `Dockerfile` to make the script more reusable: `eval $MONGORESTORE_CMD` in `mongo.sh` and `RUN MONGORESTORE_CMD='mongorestore --drop /home/dump'` in the `Dockerfile`. I thought it made sense also to call the script `/entrypoint-with-mongorestore.sh` finally.

Comment: Does the database have to be restored everytime the image is created? Shouldn't this be a "RUN" instead of a CMD? ["CMD /home/mongo.sh"]

Comment: In trying this approach, I get `/entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory`.   Changing `./entrypoint.sh` to `docker-entrypoint.sh` (note the change from absolute to relative) did the trick.

Comment: I also think the same as @AshuJoshi, wouldn't this restore the database every time the image is run?

Answer (score 14):

A similar solution to RyanNHG's, but without an sh file.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mongo:3.6.8

COPY dump/ /tmp/dump/

CMD mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log; \
    mongorestore /tmp/dump/; \
    mongod --shutdown; \
    docker-entrypoint.sh mongod
```

Comment: This works like a charm Thanks @hisener. I have been struggling for whole day then found this with little tweaks to this it helped me a lot.

Comment: Works, but the `/data/db` files are all deleted after running `mongod --shutdown`

Comment: Was able to get it working within a multi-stage build by copying `/data/db` to `/tmp/db` before `mongod --shutdown`, then within the second stage, copying from the build-stage's `/tmp/db` to `/data/db`.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question and the solution above could still work but in later versions, you can add **.sh** and **.js** scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`, which will be executed in case the instance is first loading (`/data/db` is empty).

Now, Dockerfile could look something like:

```
FROM mongo

COPY ./data-dump/ /tmp/dump/mydb/

COPY ./import_data.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import_data.sh

CMD chmod 777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import_data.sh #this is probably too permissive
```

With that, whatever is in `import_data.sh` will be run (or whatever other file(s) you have there) first time the container is started.

```
# change the mongorestore command to match your case, adding user/password and other options.
mongorestore /tmp/dump # note we can possibly restore many DBs.
```

It is documented [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) under **Initializing a fresh instance** section

Answer (score 3):

the problem isn't with docker.

If you look at the [dockerfile for mongo](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/fc91d681fa5808c30c3118ce7fe3f993beccc82d/2.6/Dockerfile) it runs `CMD ["mongod"]` which starts the mongo service.

You said `FROM MONGO` but you overwrote the `CMD` line. this means mongo never started via `mongod`. so try `CMD mongod; mongorestore /home/dump`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! And you're correct, I took a look at that file earlier tonight and realized that only the last `CMD` will run. However, with `CMD mongod; mongorestore /home/dump`, the `mongorestore` command never runs. I tried `mongod & mongorestore /home/dump` and got a little bit closer. Still no luck though.

Comment: mongod & mongorestore /home/dump will not work since mongod is running in the foreground and thus is blocking. Use the answer from ryanHNG

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use this for production but it does what you need:

```
== Dockerfile ==
FROM mongo:3

COPY restore.sh /restore.sh
COPY ./mongodump /dump/

ENTRYPOINT /restore.sh
```

then

```
== restore.sh ==
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Execute restore in the background after 5s
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d
sleep 5 && mongorestore /dump &

# Keep mongod in the foreground, otherwise the container will stop
docker-entrypoint.sh mongod
```