# mongo-restore from docker-container, sh scripts working but only manually

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to restore several collections when starting my containerized mongo instance.

This is the relevant docker-compose part (I leave some of the stuff commented so you know I tried that, but it didn't work either:

```
 mongo-container:
    container_name: my container
#    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
#    volumes:
#      - ./dump:/dump
    environment:
      MONGODB_USER: "user"
      MONGODB_PASS: "password"
#    command:
##      - sh mongorestore dump
##      - mongorestore dump -d Collection1
#        - mongorestore dump -d Collection2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_mongodb
    networks:
      - my-network
```

This is the the Dockerfile_mongodb:

```
FROM mongo

RUN mkdir /dump
COPY dump /dump
COPY run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
```

and the /run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

mongorestore /dump -d Coll1
mongorestore /dump -d Coll2
mongorestore /dump -d Coll3
```

..I also tried the solutions from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282957/mongorestore-in-a-dockerfile), none of them worked.

If I start my mongo-container with `docker-compose up mongo-container`
and then `docker exec -ti mongo-container bash`
and run `./run.sh`
it works and the db is restored. So I figure the run.sh file does not get called, but I don't know why.

Comment: A `command:` runs _instead of_ the main container process; the way you’re trying to set it up you’re trying to run a restore command in place of the database.  Using another container or another copy of the Mongo shell is the right thing to do, and it seems like the question you linked to covers the options pretty well.

Comment: I literally copied the OP's answer  and just adjusted the name of the files and it did not work..