# How to run Mongo shell command after docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I would like to start this MongoDB Replica Set:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --replSet rs0
  mongo2:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    command: mongod --replSet rs0
  mongo3:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    command: mongod --replSet rs0
```

Wait for those to come up, then access the Mongo shell via terminal:

```
docker exec -it mongo1 mongo
```

Then in Mongo shell do:

```
rs.initiate({"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo1:27017"},{"_id":1,"host":"mongo2:27017"},{"_id":2,"host":"mongo3:27017"}]})
```

Mongo also allows `mongo --eval "rs.initiate(..)"`, which may make things easier.

My question is how do I run this command after mongo1, mongo2, mongo3 are up?

Comment: What happens when you run this? I imagine you could set a container_name to make it easier?

Comment: It works if I just do it manually like that but I would like it to be automated to be deployed to the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, I recently had to run `mongo --repair` then run the MongoDB itself and after the MongoDB is up I needed to add my user to the DB, you can easily change things to run commands only after all three MongoDBs are up.

Possible docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    restart: on-failure:10
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=<user>
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=<pass>
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=db
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: bash -c "mongod --repair && mongod"

  mongoClient:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongoClient
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - ./deployment_scripts:/deployment_scripts
    command: 
      - /deployment_scripts/add_user.sh
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongoClient
    links:
      - mongo
```

My `/deployment_scripts/add_user.sh` script wait for MongoDB to be up:

```
until mongo --host mongo --eval "print(\"waited for connection\")"
do
    sleep 1
done

// you can add more MongoDB waits here

echo "Adding user to MongoDB..."
mongo --host mongo --eval "db.createUser({ user: \"<user>\", pwd: \"<pass>\", roles: [ { role: \"root\", db: \"admin\" } ] });"
echo "User added."
```

Note that you can address all three of your MongoDBs by replacing `--host mongo` with your `--host mongo1` `--host mongo2` and `--host mongo3`. You'll use this for both of the eval commands in the script.

Credit to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060399/4295037 that I used (`until mongo ...`).

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using [Oficial Mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) image, that image is configured with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mongod"]
```

If you check the docker-entrypoint.sh you will notice you could run any command you want by overwriting the CMD.

So, you can do for each mongo container

```
$ docker run -d mongo
9bf0473d491a2d7ae821bcf10ed08cd49678d28e46344589622bd9440a6aca65

$ docker ps -q
9bf0473d491a

$ docker exec -ti 9bf0473d491a mongo --eval "rs.initiate(.....)"
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.5
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
    "code" : 76,
    "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

Notice that the errmsg is just because in my example the rs.initiate() is empty, it will work for you with the right config.

Comment: Hi there. I am sorry for the stupid question, but what exactly am I supposed to edit? Do you mean pull the image, edit the image, then commit my modified image? I was hoping I could just stick an easy command in my docker-compose somehow. Also I was just trying to do `rs.initiate(...)` once after all replicas are up, not for each replica.

Comment: @kaya I don't think mongo images are configurable in that sense using just docker-compose. I would advise using docker exec to configure after deployment. My guess is it would take some extensive work to be able to dynamically add a MongoDB Replica set using just docker-compose configuration.

Comment: @kayla , edit the rs.initiate(...) and replace the ... with your own json config to initiate the RS.